# How to plot continuous heatmap of points in 2D

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset like this:

```
import numpy as np
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 100, 1), np.arange(0, 100, 1))
loc = np.array([x.flatten(), y.flatten()]).T
vals = np.random.rand(10000).reshape(100, 100)
```

or with more structured distribution:

```
vals = mvn.pdf(loc,[50, 24], np.array([[ 5 , -2 ], [-2 ,  7]])) + \
       mvn.pdf(loc, [20, 60], np.array([[20, 30], [40, 90]])) + \
       0.4
vals = vals / max(vals)
vals = vals.reshape(100, 100)
```

All my values are on the [0, 1] scale. I want to plot distribution of vals in nice, continuous way. What I have in mind is a sort of heatmap that would continuously change its color dependent on a value. As for know, my only idea is `plt.contour` - however, I'm not satisfied with the results.

[image]
[image]

What alternatives do I have in `matplotlib`? How to make it "more continuous" in the case of second `vals`?

Comment: I don't understand.  Would it work to smooth the data and then plot it?

Comment: For a uniform random distribution, I can't see what exactly you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used this for my RAMPIS-C program in 2d graphing. If you would like to animate it you need to do the following:

```
import random #I used this for my data

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   #Used to plot data
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation   #Animation function from matplotlib

x_vals = list()  #Your data my x y preset lists
y_vals = list()

def Animate(I): #Create an animation function
    #Below I create my randomized data over time
    x_vals.append(random.randint(0,5))
    y_vals.append(random.randint(0,5))
    #The following create the graph
    plt.cla() #This clears the graph color such that you don't have issues with randomized colors
    plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals) #This plots the data, use whatever function you want for this

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), Animate, interval=100) #The following "Animates" the graph
#Your interval is in ms

plt.tight_layout() #Nicer layout for data, likely not needed in your code
plt.show() #Shows the plot
```

Comment: Notes: If you would like a better "heat-map" you can use camp, some code for a 3d graphing I have for my RAMPIS-C model is below:

Comment: Notes: If you would like a better "heat-map" you can use camp, some code for a 3d graphing I have for my RAMPIS-C model is below:



surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)



cmap will create a heat map effect

Comment: as for creating a surface, you may want to create a 3d graph, I do not know how well matplotlib can create a 2d graph with a heatmap like precision similar to contour, so using 3d graphing may be your only choice in matplotlib